# $\sigma(x) = \sigma^{-1}(x)$

Tags: exponential-function

I want to find the solution to $\sigma(x) =\sigma^{-1}(x)$ Where $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and so $\sigma^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)-\ln(1-x)$. I've got it down to $\frac{e^x}{x}=e^x+1$ but I can't get any further. Desmos tells me that the solution is around $0.659$ but I want an exact expression for it... Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe an analytic closed form solution exists.

Comment: @mathreadler nothing in particular, just trying to get a feel for the sigmoid function for working with neural networks

Comment: Okay, thank you :)) @superckl

Comment: Maybe Lamberts W function could help you express the solution. I dont see how this particular equation gives any insight into neural networks. Why don't you build some intuition for the multivariate chain rule instead.

Comment: The equation that you derived is simply $\sigma(x) =x$. But that's not the original.

Comment: But well, since your function is a strict contraction, Banach's fixed point theorem tells us that your original equation ($\sigma^2(x) = x$) and $\sigma(x)=x$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe your equation has an analytic solution. You can, however, get close by trying some approximations. Let's rewrite our equation as

$$e^x=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Say we expand the functions into a Taylor series

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+...$$
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=x-x^2+...$$

Dropping higher order terms, we have

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}=x+x^2$$

which, when simplified, gives us

$$x^2-2=0$$

Which tells us $x=\pm\sqrt{2}\approx1.414$

Okay not great... but adding another higher order term gives us

$$5x^3+3x^2-6=0$$

Which has one real root at $x\approx.895$. Adding the fourth order term gives $x\approx.767$. A fifth gives $x\approx.716$.

By the time you've reached seventh order terms, your approximation is at $x\approx.679$ which is within 3% of the actual answer. This is just one way to get at the solution by using functions we know the solutions to.

Comment: Well, "by using functions we know the solutions to" is not quite correct. I mean, determining the roots of a 7th order polynomial can also only be done numerically.

Comment: I suppose that's correct, I meant they are more "familiar" in a sense.

Comment: Polynomials might be more familiar. However, this doesn't give you nothing for retrieving the roots. Also, polynomials have several roots, while the given function $\sigma(x)-x$ only has a single root. I think Newton's method works better here.

Comment: I would agree, I've never claimed this method is better. It's simply an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

To find a root of $g(x)=(x-1)e^x+x$ in $[0,1]$ is numerically pretty simple since such function is convex and increasing over $[0,1]$. By initializing Newton's method
$$ z_{n+1} = z_n - \frac{g(z_n)}{g'(z_n)} $$
at $z_0=1$ we get $z_2<\frac{2}{3}$ and $z_4=\color{green}{0.659046}\ldots$
You might have an explicit representation of such constant in terms of Lambert $W$ function, but the computation of $W$ still is performed through Newton's method, raising an interesting debate about what *explicit* really means.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second order approximation of $\textbf{exp}$ i.e $e^x \approx 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}$. We would then have,

$$\frac{e^x}{x} = e^x + 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}}{x} \approx \left(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2!}\right)+1$$

The above implies,

$$1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2!}  \approx 2x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{2!} $$

And so $x$ will be approximately the root of,

$$ p(u) =u^3 + u^2 + 2u-2 $$

Now you can use intermediate value theorem first noting that $p(.5)<0$ and $p(1)>0$ i.e your zero lies in the interval $[.5,1]$. If you want to approach this from a qualitative point of view. I would just keep increasing $.5$ until $p(.5+ \epsilon)>0$. In any case, at least now you can an expression which approximates the root.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the value approximated by your computation system is correct. Using algebraic adjustments we can determine an equality: $$-\log\left({\frac{1}{x}-1}\right)= \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$ 
The only possible way to evaluate the solution to this equation is explicitly numeric, therefore indescribable as an analytical expression. The closest thing to get an explicit number I can think of is a convergence of Fourier or Taylor series, which *can* be described as an infinite sum of functions. There should not exist any way to do this precisely and nothing should be more precise considering absolute convergence than those series.